# NumberFormatException while converting from string to byte

Tags: java, byte

I am coming across a strange thing. I have a number in binary in the form of string particularly "01001100". But I am getting the exception mentioned above by executing the following code.

```
String s = "01001100";
byte b = Byte.parseByte(s);
```

But why is it happening? Whereas in a byte we can store max no. upto 127 and min. upto -128.
And the decimal equivalent of the above number is 76 which is perfectly in the range.

*The particular  exception I am getting is as:*

**java.lang.NumberFormatException:Value out of range. value:01001100 radix:10**

Is there any way to get rid of it. Yes and it is compulsory for me to use byte only as I am extracting the data stored in the image byte by byte only.
Thank you.

Comment: @all: Thank you very much. :). I have the version supporting the method!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key is at the end of the exception string: `radix:10`. You are converting the decimal value 1,001,100 to a byte, and it does not fit. Try this:

```
String s = "01001100";
byte b = Byte.parseByte(s, 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

`01001100` is a fairly large number in decimal (over a million; see [the docs for `parseByte(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String%29)). You probably want [the version that accepts a radix](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte(s, 2);
```